# How to add multiple modules with -add-modules

Tags: java, directory, command, virtual-machine, system

I would like to add multiple modules through the VM options in NetBeans. Currently i have just added 1 module( javafx.controls).

[image]

Here is the directory that has all the modules including the one already added.
[image]

Does anyone know the separating delimiter?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the comma character: `,`

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE) says:

> ```
> --add-modules <module name>[,<module name>...]
>               root modules to resolve in addition to the initial module.
>               <module name> can also be ALL-DEFAULT, ALL-SYSTEM,
>               ALL-MODULE-PATH.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

To run JavaFX you have to tell your VM where modules are:

```
--module-path /Users/sbrbot/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib
```

and then tell what modules to use:

```
--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

Answer (score 0):

--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED

maybe this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).